# uninstall mongodb php driver and install a different version

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu Xampp (Lampp) and currently on MongoDB `1.5.3` driver.

I need to downgrade to `1.4.5`, but when re-installed the downgraded driver, it does not change in `phpinfo()`. Yes, I have restarted Apache.

So, how do I uninstall the current one and install the downgraded version?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update: 2018-06-20:**

PECL package [mongo](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongo) is now deprecated, you should use [mongodb](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) package instead:

`sudo pecl install -f mongodb-1.4.4`

**Original answer**

You can upgrade to a specific version of a driver by using pecl:

`sudo pecl install -f mongo-1.4.5`

If you get a `pecl: command not found` error you will need to install PEAR package:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install php-pear
```

You can use this command to check that you have the correct version installed:

```
sudo pecl info mongo
```

Or you can check php configuration directly with:

```
php -i | grep -A 1 MongoDB
```