# Install MongoDbBundle with Symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, composer-php

I want to setup MongoDbBundle with my Symfony2 app. But I getting theese error list when run `composer update`:

```
Problem 1
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.9 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.8 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.7 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.6 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.5 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.4 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.5-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.11 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.7-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.10 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.7-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.1 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.4-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.1.8 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.7-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.1.7 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.7-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.1.6 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb 1.1.5 requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.6-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA5 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1 -> no matching package found.
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA4 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.0-BETA1 -> no matching package found.
- symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.5.x-dev requires doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.*@beta -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb-odm[1.0.0-BETA10, 1.0.0-BETA11, 1.0.0-BETA12, 1.0.0-BETA4, 1.0.0-BETA5, 1.0.0-BETA6, 1.0.0-BETA7, 1.0.0-BETA8, 1.0.0-BETA9].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA6 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.0.0-beta1,<1.1-dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA7 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA8 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA9 requires doctrine/mongodb 1.0.* -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA10 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA11 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8].
- doctrine/mongodb-odm 1.0.0-BETA12 requires doctrine/mongodb >=1.1.5,<2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8].
- Installation request for symfony/framework-standard-edition 2.5.x-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-standard-edition[2.5.x-dev].
```

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116235/uninstall-mongodb-php-driver-and-install-a-different-version), downgrade my php mongo extension update compsoer.phar  but still getting same error. What I am doing wrong ?

Here is my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
    "hautelook/alice-bundle": "~0.2",
    "nelmio/alice": "~1.7",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "1.0.*@beta",
    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "3.0.*@beta"
},
```

**Edit**

I even try to change "minimum-stability" property. Downgrade ext-mongo to 1.4.5 and 1.2.12 versions. Still have the same error.

**SOLVING**

Solve this by run in cli : `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo`

Comment: I think is is a simular question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869846/cant-install-mongodb-doctrine-in-symfony2-with-composer

Comment: @user3678743, i enable mongo extension in ini file

Comment: Installing php56-mongo (since i am working with php 5.6.7) worked for me.    On mac with homebrew this makes it `brew install php56-mongo`. Took me half the day to get this working

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-mongo` solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you have the mongo extension ?

run this from console

```
 php -i | grep mongo
```

are there the mongo configs ?

if so add

```
phpinfo();
```

to your app/app_dev.php
and check if Symfony(apache) is using another php than your shell PATH

UPDTE:

as pointed out in comments, your apache uses another php than you expect
point the apache to the correct php extension path in httpd.conf

Comment: hm... when I run `sudo pecl info mongo` it return result, but when run 
`php -i | grep mongo` it just thhor me to print new command...

Comment: what prints the phpinfo() in app_dev.php ? are there mongo configs ?

Comment: hm. no. there is no mongo configs. but I cant get why. I install it, enable extension in ini file.

Comment: then have a look at httpd.conf and check which php .so is included, this seems to be wrong, most likely at at /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

Comment: http://www.commanigy.com/blog/2011/06/08/finding-apache-configuration-file-httpd-conf-location

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution for osx:

> brew install php56-mongo

if it errors out then read the package name and re-run such as - example:

> example: brew install php5789-mongo

source: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx